# 14.04 Upgrade triggers grub-pc failure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade

My problem begins with an upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.02 LTS. As part of this I received several error messages about not being able to remove old kernels.

When first booting into 14.02, I checked everything was ok by running `sudo apt-get autoremove`, the same errors appeared.

Following a guide online, I ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge grub-common
sudo apt-get install grub-pc
```

The first operation succeeded, removing grub from my pc. The second operation failed with the following:

```
Creating config file /etc/default/grub with new version
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-54-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
cat: /video.lst: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `'.
No path or device is specified.
Usage: grub-probe [OPTION...] [OPTION]... [PATH|DEVICE]
Try 'grub-probe --help' or 'grub-probe --usage' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried numerous fixes for this, most of which are documented [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099). I created a LiveCD before removing `grub-common`, so I have access to my old partition and can `mount` and `chroot` into it.

But when running `update-grub` the same error appears, I also cannot run `dpkg --configure -a` without this occurring.

I used `boot-repair` to get [a boot summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11715934/) for my machine, which is a 2 HDD rig with dual boot on the first drive (`/dev/sda`). With `Windows` on `/dev/sda1` and my `Ubuntu` partition (also boot) on `/dev/sda2`.

Please help me fix this and I promise I won't touch my Ubuntu install ever again. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I *"elegantly solved"* my problem by using the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge grub-pc grub-common
sudo rm -r /etc/grub.d/
sudo apt-get install grub-pc grub-common
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Deleting the `/etc/grub.d/` directory seemed to have gotten rid of whatever `12.04` files I had lurking, allowing `14.04` to get on with installing grub!

Although I would of course recommend making a backup of anything that you are about to delete.

Comment: This does solve the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: DANGER you might not want to run such `rm -r` commands ... at the very least, back up what you remove. And also this solution is missing `update-initramfs -u` which is often important for fixng boot issues.

Comment: I found this question while looking for a solution w.r.t. the message `dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure)` which I was getting when running `apt upgrade`. Doing only `apt-get purge grub-pc grub-common; apt-get install grub-pc grub-common; update-grub` solved the problem.

Comment: This also fixed a problem for me on 20.10 where ubuntu just decided it didn't want to boot anymore :-(

Answer (score 1):

these grub errors have been ongoing for many years and even now on 20.04 ... just run these

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install -y
sudo apt-get -f install -y 
sudo  apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" -yy dist-upgrade -yq
sudo apt-get autoremove -yq
sudo apt-get autoclean -y
```

if output of above shows some flareup then just rerun all of above again and you will be good to go

Comment: Hi Scott, could you please help, I am also facing the same issue with my 20.04. I did what you mentioned but I keep on getting: ```Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic
 linux-image-5.4.0-51-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use Boot-Repair is to create a disk containing the tool (eg Boot-Repair-Disk, a disk starting Boot-Repair automatically), and boot on it.

I personally prefer using the [Boot-Repair disk ISO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

Comment: Boot-repair has been 0-3 for me.