# System boots to grub prompt only

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair, 20.10

Ubuntu 20.10
Computer boots to grub prompt.  I can manually launch my OS like this, no problem:

```
grub> linux (hd0,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-33-generic root=/dev/sda2
grub> initrd (hd0,gpt2)/boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-33-generic
grub> boot
```

And it boots right in (I'm on it right now).  I just can't for the life of me remember how to make this automatic.  I also am unsure why it quit working in the first place.

I tried the boot-repair tool to no effect.

Here is /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

#GRUB_DEFAULT=10
GRUB_DEFAULT=1
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

#GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Post the link to the boot-repair report.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo update-grub` in the terminal after booting into Ubuntu?

Comment: This is working but I'm getting an error complaining about grub not existing

menuentry "Kubuntu" {
          search --set=root --label GRUB --hint (hd0,gpt2)
          linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-33-generic root=/dev/sda2
          initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-33-generic
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: Running update-grub does nothing to fix the issue.  I don't have a boot-repair report.

Comment: On another note, I really wish I knew WHY this problem happened in the first place.  The only thing I was doing recently was attempting to install the latest amd graphics drivers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the problem for me in grub.cfg and removed the search error as well:

```
menuentry "Kubuntu" {
          insmod part_gpt
          insmod fat
          set root='hd0,gpt2'
          linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-33-generic root=UUID=79ff29a1-eb9c-4463-a39c-77b98c1a97f5 rw
          initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-33-generic
}
```

I also grabbed the answer from [14.04 Upgrade triggers grub-pc failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636456/14-04-upgrade-triggers-grub-pc-failure) using Rossiar's answer to get a nice clean reset, so actually, that is the best answer:

```
sudo apt-get purge grub-pc grub-common
sudo rm -r /etc/grub.d/
sudo apt-get install grub-pc grub-common
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

I also found something to more easily modify grub once you set it up the way you like.  It's a gui program called Grub Customizer.  Package installs -> `apt install grub-customizer`

Quick and easy tutorial here: https://itsfoss.com/customize-grub-linux/